# Find element in xml

Tags: xml, python-2.7

I need to find an element in a xml file.
My challenge is that the element name is dynamic and i only know the parent element.

as an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config version="1.0" timestamp="xxxxxxxxxx">
    <a>
        <aa>
        ..
        </aa>
    <b>
        <bb>
        ...
        </bb>
    <c>
        <cc>
            <ccc>
                <cccc>
                    <????>.......</????>
                </cccc>
```

I need to find the element ???? and read it's value.
I've already tried this;

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
.....
for x in root.iter("cccc"):
   for y in x.iter():
   .....
```

But that doesn't seem the right solution.
I appreciate your answer.
Regards,
Robertico

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the parent element and get the first child:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = """<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config version="1.0" timestamp="xxxxxxxxxx">
    <a>
        <aa>
        ..
        </aa>
    </a>
    <b>
        <bb>
        ...
        </bb>
    </b>
    <c>
        <cc>
            <ccc>
                <cccc>
                    <test>value to find</test>
                </cccc>
            </ccc>
        </cc>
    </c>
</config>"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)

parent = tree.find('.//cccc')
print next(iter(parent)).text
```

prints:

```
value to find
```

Or, thanks to @falsetru, just do `print tree.find('.//cccc/*').text`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'd rather do `tree.find('.//cccc/*').text`

Comment: @falsetru me too :) Thought that due to limited xpath support it won't work. Thanks.